# Converting Celsius Processor Temperature to Fahrenheit

Tags: command-line, conky, bc

I'm editing a Conky theme.  I would like it to output the processor temperatures in degrees Fahrenheit instead of Celsius.

In the `~/.conkyrc` file, the command `sensors | grep 'Core 0' | cut -c18-19` is used to find the temperature in Celsius  for the first processor core.  I want to use `bc` to compute this (give it `outputvalue*9/5+32`).

Problem is, `bc` wants just absolute values, and I see no way to pass it program output.  If I try to use something like `temp=$(sensors | grep 'Core 0' | cut -c18-19) & echo 'temp*9/5+32' | bc`, it ends up giving me 32 because it registers "temp" as a 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Conky help](http://conky.sourceforge.net/docs.html), you can specify this in the config file  ~/.conkyrc

Quote:

> temperature_unit
>
> - Desired output unit of all objects displaying a temperature. Parameters are either "fahrenheit" or "celsius". The default unit is
>     degree Celsius.

Answer (score 5):

You need `echo $temp*9/5+32 | bc`.  Variables are prefixed with a `$` and can not be inside single quotes.

Comment: Both of these answers are correct!  This works too but fabricator4 has less rep.  Thanks!

Comment: @WindowsEscapist, his answer is also a more direct answer to your question, I just wanted to explain what was wrong with your approach.

Comment: It seemed like the conky switch was the way to do it.  I came across various methods in my research including the use of awk scripts that poll the sensor module directly.  It's certainly a powerful way to do it, but perhaps a little more complicated than is warranted.

Comment: He would also want `&&` instead of `&` so that the value of temp is calcucated *before* calling `bc`

Comment: @psusi I think I'm actually going to use this instead of the switch =p.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @glennjackman, true... I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Get your $temp, and assuming /bin/bash why not just do this:

```
echo $[(${temp}*9/5)+32]
```